# How to close Excel c#

Tags: c#, excel

this is my code, I have seen others closing excel sheets this way but why does this not work. There are no errors in the code execution but the app still seems to be running in the background

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook Sheet = Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\Maxine\\Testing.xlsx");
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet x = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)Excel.ActiveSheet);
            Sheet.Close(false,Type.Missing,Type.Missing);
            Excel.Quit();
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: nothing, just executes and leaves the app running in the background

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly clean up Excel interop objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-do-i-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Proper way to open and close an excel file programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30792531/c-sharp-proper-way-to-open-and-close-an-excel-file-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually release the COM object. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject(v=vs.110).aspx), but you need to do `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject` on the Excel object.

Comment: I tried using it and the result of the call is 0 but the program is still running in the background

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook Sheet = Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\JustinNew\\Desktop\\Testing.xlsx");
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet x = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)Excel.ActiveSheet);
            Sheet.Close(false,Type.Missing,Type.Missing);
            Excel.Quit();
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(Excel);

Am i using this right?

Comment: @MaxPrice You need to release your WorkSheet, your Workbook and your Excel Application check the question I marked as duplicate.